# google chrome issue with fixed position and margin-top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome

Funky problem in Chrome:

I have this social-icons `div` in the layout of my rails app:

```
<div class="social_media_icons">
  <ul>
    <li ><a href="http://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/yt.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li ><a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="/images/fb.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li ><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="/images/tw.jpg" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And relevent css:

```
.social_media_icons{
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -69%;
}
```

That I am moving around the screen with `@media` queries. Now the `@media` works fine for width but not so good for height. So when the content changes and the height of page gets larger or smaller I have a javascript function that changes the margin-top of the `div`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if(document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1101){
      if($(".container").height() > 600 && $(".container").height() < 1299){
          $(".social_media_icons").css("margin-top", "-115%"); //problem right here
      } else if($(".container").height() > 1300){
          $(".social_media_icons").css("margin-top", "-273%"); //problem right here
      } else if($(".container").height() <= 500){
          $(".social_media_icons").css("margin-top", "-45%");
      } else{
          $(".social_media_icons").css("margin-top", "-68%");
      }
  }
});
```

As you can see the values for the `margin-top`, on the commented lines, (`-115%` and `-273%` respectively) are a little messed up! And of course those values don't work at all in FF or IE.

**Question:** Why is Chrome requiring such absurd values for the % of `margin-top` when the content on the page gets any larger then `600px`?

In fact why am I having to change the % of `margin-top` at all? Shouldn't it be relative to the view window on a `fixed` element? Which would mean that setting the value of `margin-top` once, should position it in the exact same place no matter the content because the `view-port` height never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
.social_media_icons{
float: left;
position: fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position